# Android GPS Not Updating Despite minTime of 0 and minDistance of 0

Tags: android, gps

I've been working on an application that emails the GPS location of a phone to the user- and it is very important that the phone sends the current location, not the location from a while ago.

I tried a couple fixes, such as changing minTime and minDist, as well as removing (or not removing) the listener when done. This application is to be used only at certain times, however, and I want minimum battery use, so leaving it running isn't a good option.

I have had luck with some updating if I set the minTime to a small amount, and never removed the LocationListener, in which case the second message I sent would be updated, but other than that...

This makes me think I need to give it more time to get the GPS location for sure- but how would I force it to do that?

With this in mind, I have been trying this snippet:

> ```
>   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>     LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
>                 Bundle extras) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         }
>     };      
>     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (long)(.000001), (float)(0),
>             locationListener);      
>     String s = "";
>     SimpleDateFormat timingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
>     timingFormat.format(new Date());
>     s += "The current time according to the clock is: "
>             + timingFormat.format(new Date()) + "\n";
>     Location location = lm
>             .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
>     lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
> ```
>
> (returns the String s, with the address added)

Answer (score 0):

You should put something in `onLocationChanged` to do something with the location updates coming in.

Normally you first get a rough approximation, and when the GPS tunes in the accuracy gets better. To handle this efficiently, have `onLocationChanged` check if the location is accurate enough, and let it kick off whatever you want to do with the accurate location.

A good start would be to just put

```
Log.v("myapp","Location changed: "+location);
```

in `onLocationChanged()` and then watch the output.